# Is it possible to make Android text to speech's language, different from device language?

Tags: android, multilingual, text-to-speech

I want , for example, to have the language in my device set to "italian" and have the TTS speaking english inside my app.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

use the setLanguage method

```
TextToSpeech mTts;
mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
//mTts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.FRANCE)
```

Refer to this [Link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html) Section **Languages and Locale**

I advice you to see the Google I/O [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uX9nt8Cpdqg#t=6m17s)

The text to speech Default Settings Overrides your App Setting

you can prompt the user to the text to speech setting by used intent and asking him to erase the default setting:

```
ComponentName componentToLaunch = new ComponentName(
        "com.android.settings",
        "com.android.settings.TextToSpeechSettings");
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(componentToLaunch);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding; but i already used this in vain.
I figuerd it out by  manually uncheck the "always use my settings" checkbox under Text To Speech Settings.
Now i have to figure out how to do this programmatically, have you any clue ? ^^

Comment: you can prompt the text to speech preference screen to the user and ask him to uncheck default setting!!

Comment: It's a possibility but it's messy, i want a clean way of doing this by code, i will keep searching, thx.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Using Text-to-Speech](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html) You can set the language of your **TextToSpeech** object using **setLanguage** like:

```
mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US); // here mTs is a TextToSpeech object
```

So, what you want shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding; but i already used this in vain. I figuerd it out by manually uncheck the "always use my settings" checkbox under Text To Speech Settings. Now i have to figure out how to do this programmatically, have you any clue ? ^^

Comment: From [this](http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/check-text-to-speech-always-use-my-settings-t11675.html) you can check if "always use my settings" is checked or not and prompt user accordingly.